# Facebook login Popup blocked on iphone event with click event - javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two problems, I searched a lot and all solutions didn't work for me.
I work on iphone/ios 9.2, Facebook Javascript sdk 2.5v

1- I try to make facebook login (FB.login()) appear as a popup window.
I tried open it after user event (click on button/link), but to success.
Also, I tried to open facebook login link in (window.open()) javascript, but this also doesn't work on iphone.

2- After facebook login through the redirect-uri to previous link fails, some of page components disappear from screen

> architect view did fail to load navigation 'navigation: original URL:
>   'OUR_HTML_LINK_ON_SERVER' - final URL: 'OUR_HTML_LINK_ON_SERVER'
>   - isLoading: '0' - wasInterrupted: '0''  with error 'Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=1693916227561341&domain=epic-demo.com&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df7cf73a4%26domain%3Depic-demo.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fepic-demo.com%252Ff19806b4fc%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=1693916227561341&domain=epic-demo.com&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df7cf73a4%26domain%3Depic-demo.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fepic-demo.com%252Ff19806b4fc%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey}'

I used this code:

```
           $('#link').click(function (){
               FB.ui({method: 'oauth',
                   client_id:'1693916227561341',
                   api_key:'1693916227561341',
                   app_id:'1693916227561341',
                   canvas:'1',
                   fbconnect:'1',
                   response_type:'code token',
                   perms:'email',
                   scope:'email',
                   redirect_uri:document.location.href
                   }, myCallback);
           });
```

And this:

```
$('#link').click(function (){
    FB.login();
});
```

Note: I use feed dialog as a popup successfully, but share dialog not.

How can I solve any of this ?
Thank you,

Comment: I don't fully understand what are trying to do and how it differs with what is happening currently. You shouldn't try to alter the behaviour of the provided dialogs, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Login dialog appears as a full screen, and I need it just a dialog which appears as a popup, not full screen. Also after login, it doesn't redirect will to html main page and this log error appear.

Comment: You can't change that behaviour.

Comment: but from options of FB.ui:{ display : 'popup' }